# How to use docstring as Python unittest description?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am using Python 3.4.3. All docstring in test_*** methods is ignored.

```
class MovieQueriesTest(ApiBaseTest):
    """Tests for query operations against movies endpoint"""

    def test_query_empty_result(self):
        """
        Query which yields empty results must be well-formed
        """
        response = self.client.get('/api/movies')
        self.assert200(response, 'Empty movie response should have status 200')
```

Docstring `Tests for query operations against movies endpoint` is not collected but the test method name `test_query_empty_result` is.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just how Pycharm's [Monitoring and Managing Tests](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/monitoring-and-managing-tests.html) functionality implemented. I am afraid you cannot configure it to show docstrings instead of test names.